# Is there a way to use a class in functions.php of child theme that has already been instantiated in the parent theme functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, child-theming

I have a class in a file of a theme, this file is required in the `functions.php`. If I try to require it in the child theme `functions.php` I have this error:

`Fatal error: Cannot declare class Martfury_WooCommerce, because the name is already in use in...`

It happens because I'm requiring the file with the class twice:

The question is, is there a away to use this class in the child theme `functions.php`?

Theme require and use of the file:

```
global $martfury_woocommerce;
$martfury_woocommerce = new Martfury_WooCommerce;

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/frontend/woocommerce.php';
```

Comment: You probably don't need to require it again in your child theme. But what happens if you do `require_once` instead of `require` in both files?

Comment: the thing is that i want to use the class to remove an action: 
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'fbt_product' ), 5 );`